# Access VBA error "Too few parameters. Expected 1"

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to find out why this is wrong, while in the queries generator it works properly.

```
SELECT Count(Audi.Id) AS CuentaDeId FROM Audi
    WHERE (((Len." & filtro & ") Between #" & Format(Me!fechamin, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & Format(Me!fechamax, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#))
```

With some dates slightly different It works, but I think that when It does not find any value in this Table, the error appears.
No idea if it's a problem of the Query design, or if there is another way to define it, or not. Any clue, anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An Audi table? Do you have a BMW table too? Consider having one common table for all cars!

Comment: What is `Len.` alias as it is not defined in query?

Comment: What are your regional date settings?  Would you typically use mm/dd/yyy ?

Comment: What is Audi? A query? What is filtro? Can the date controls be empty (Null)?

Answer (score 0):

Len is a function name in SQL. That is why Access asked for the parameter. Besides, as Parfait said, Len is used in your query as an alias but not referring to any other table/query.